# python tkinter autocomplete entry: How to reset it and how to change the search pattern?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have used a tkinter autocomplete widget. I got code from here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578253-an-entry-with-autocompletion-for-the-tkinter-gui/

Now I have two problems. One is that when user clicks on clear button, this autocomplete widget should reset to "".

So I added an extra resetauto function within the code given above like this:

```
def resetauto():
    self.var.set("")
```

And in my clear button function, I used this reset like this:

```
W2.resetauto(); # W2 is the name of the autocomplete entry widget
```

But when I ran the program again and tried to reset it, I got error:

```
W2.resetauto()
TypeError: resetauto() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Also I have another problem. For this autocomplete widget, I have a dataset of 4000 words. And all these words start "rs" for example, rs123, rs485459, etc. So if user starts typing rs, it will display 4000 words. Instead of that, I want this autocomplete widget to start matching from the 3rd character of the input. Is it possible? can you explain in brief what will i have to change looking at the code of this widget from the link. thanks...

Comment: what's `resetauto()` here?where is it getting called?

Comment: oh i forgot the function name is reset auto wait i will edit the question

Comment: should be `def resetauto(self):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a class named `AutocompleteEntry` and you are defining `resetauto` inside the class, you must define it as a standard class method with `self` as the first parameter. For example:

```
def resetauto(self):
    ...
```

As for being able to match only after three characters have been entered, it looks like all you need to do is modify `comparison`, since that is what is returning the list. Perhaps this would do the trick -- it only returns a list of the pattern if you've entered at least three characters:

```
def comparison(self):
    if len(self.var.get()) < 3:
        return []
    pattern = re.compile('.*' + self.var.get() + '.*')
    return [w for w in self.lista if re.match(pattern, w)]
```